# Neo4J - WHERE ALL clause is breaking the match on nodes

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to return two sets of nodes and then return them as a single set.

I have a WHERE ALL clause that breaks the query and I can't figure out why.

I would also like to know how to concatenate two collections of nodes, so append childItems to parentItems in a single level list. I don't believe I am doing it correctly with the '+'.

```
MATCH (ic: itemCollection)-[:CONTAINS]->(ii: itemInstance)
WITH COLLECT(ii) AS parentItem, ic, ii
OPTIONAL MATCH p = (ii)-[*]->(:item)-[:INSTANCE]->(childItem: ItemInstance)
// get asset children
SET ic.lastAccess = timestamp()
WITH parentItem, [n IN nodes(p) WHERE 'itemInstance' 
IN labels(n) AND NOT(n.id = ii.id) | n] AS childItems, p, ic
// RETURN parentItem, childItems - will return the parentItem node, and the childItem nodes here, but not after the WHERE ALL clause
WHERE ALL(n IN childItems WHERE (ic)-[:CONTAINS]-(n))
//merge parent with children
WITH parentItem , childItems, p
WITH parentItem + childItems AS itemList, p
UNWIND itemList AS item
RETURN item
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, your query has other issues. E.g., `parentItem` will always have only contain one node since `ii` is used as one of the aggregation grouping keys. Also, do you really need the `MATCH` to be `OPTIONAL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE ALL` breaks if `p` is null. To get around this, I use `coalesce(childAssets, [])` to transform the null into an empty list.